# How to let the user provide an installation prefix for a dependency in AutoConf?

Tags: dependencies, command-line-arguments, configure, autotools, autoconf

Some time ago I saw a configure script somewhere that had the possibility to specify the installation prefix of a dependency, but I don't know where that was, so I ask you to tell me how to implement this. Example:

I have a program `foo` that depends on a library `bar`. But `bar`'s installation prefix is `/home/user/.local` instead of `/usr`. For that reason, `configure` will fail to find `bar`, though it is installed. How can I let the user provide an argument to `configure` containing the installation prefix of a dependency ? The command line would maybe look like the following:

```sh
~/foo$ ./configure --bar-dir=/home/user/.local
```

**EDIT**: I found following paragraph in [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Configuration.html#Configuration)

> #### `--with-package`
>
> The package *package* will be installed, so configure this package to work with *package*.
>
> [...]
>
> ***Do not use a ‘--with’ option to specify the file name to use to find certain files. That is outside the scope of what ‘--with’ options are for***.

Okay, but when *what option should I use `"to specify the file name to use to find certain files"`* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notwithstanding the manual's objection to the practice, it is relatively common for `configure` scripts to support this via a `--with` option, so that the appropriate command line takes the form:

```sh
    ~/foo$ ./configure --with-bar-dir=/home/user/.local
```

That difference follows in large part from the fact that there are only two built-in mechanisms for making `configure` recognize additional command-line arguments: [`AC_ARG_ENABLE`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/autoconf.html#index-AC_005fARG_005fENABLE) and [`AC_ARG_WITH`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/autoconf.html#index-AC_005fARG_005fWITH), and these provide for arguments with corresponding idiosyncratic forms.  The `--with-xyzzy=...` form provided by the latter makes more sense for specifying a library directory than the `--enable-xyzzy=...` form provided by the former.

For example, you might use this in your `configure.ac`:

```
AC_ARG_WITH(
  [bar-dir],
  [AS_HELP_STRING(
    [--with-bar-dir=@<:@directory@:>@],
    [Specify directory as the location of libbar]
   )],
  [bar_ldflags="-L${withval}"]
)
```

Do read the documentation (linked above), as I've given only a taste of what `AC_ARG_WITH` does.

How you use the data received this way depends on what else you want to do.  You might put it straight into an output variable and let `configure` otherwise ignore it, but if you're using `AC_CHECK_LIB` or `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` to check for the library then you will need to put it in `LDFLAGS` for those tests.  `LDFLAGS` is a user variable, however, so you should not make permanent changes to it:

```
LDFLAGS_save=$LDFLAGS
LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} ${bar_ldflags}"
AC_CHECK_LIB([bar], [bar_init])
LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS_save
```

That would be combined with putting the flags from `bar_ldflags` into an output variable and writing `Makefile.in` or `Makefile.am` such that it is included among the link flags.

---

You also write:

> Okay, but when what option should I use `"to specify the file name to use to find certain files"` [if I don't use a `--with` argument] ?

Supposing that we also reject `--enable` arguments, the only other option provided by Autoconf is environment variables.  If you plan to rely on an environment variable, then you probably want to use [`AC_ARG_VAR()`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/autoconf.html#index-AC_005fARG_005fVAR) to tell Autoconf about it.  That will enable you to get it documented in `configure`'s help text, will automatically make it an output variable (without an explicit `AC_SUBST`) and it will make the variable "precious", such that `configure` will memorialize its value for re-use when the build system automatically re`configure`s.

Comment: `@<:@directory@:>@` - Can you please explain what that means / does ? It's gibberish to me …

Comment: @Programmer, the `@<:@` and `@:>@` are Autoconf [quadrigraphs](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/autoconf.html#Quadrigraphs), representing the characters `[` and `]`, respectively.  The whole construct thus represents the text `[directory]`, but ensures that Autoconf does not interpret the `[` and `]` as quote characters.